# Error creating a migrate from a foreign key table (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: laravel

In my migration operation I intend to create two tables: `hunter` and `master`, the table `master` contains the foreign key of `hunter`. When running `php artisan migrate` the following error occurs: **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `teste`.`master` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
(SQL: alter table `master` add constraint `master_id_hunter_foreign` foreign key (`id_hunter`) references `id_hunters` (`id`))**, I don't understand what mistake i'm making.

Not to mention that when using `php migration:rollback` the `master` and `migrations` tables is not deleted.

- `Migration hunter`

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hunter', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id_hunter');
            $table->string('name_hunter', 50);
            $table->integer('age_hunter');
            $table->decimal('weight_hunter', 5,2);
            $table->decimal('heigth_hunter', 3,2);
            $table->string('type_hunter', 30);
            $table->string('nen_hunter', 30);
            $table->string('type_blood', 3);
            $table->timestamp('date_insert')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('date_update')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
        });
    }
    
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('hunter');
    }
```

- `Migration master`

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('master', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id_master');
            $table->foreignId('id_hunter')->constrained();
            $table->string('name_master', 50);
            $table->string('nen_master', 30);
        });
    }
    
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('master');
    }
```

Comment: You are not following the Laravel conventions when it comes to naming identifiers so you need to specify the table name i.e. `->constrained('hunter')` though I do strongly suggest you follow the Laravel naming conventions for your DB i.e. use `id` for your id column name and `hunter_id` for your foreign key name (and table names should be plural form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `migrate hunter` file:

```
$table->id(); // Removed 'id_hunter'
```

In the `migrate master` file:

```
$table->id(); // Removed 'id_master'
$table->foreignId('id_hunter')->constrained('hunter'); // Added ´hunter´ in constrained()
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to inside you master migration
$table->foreign('id_hunter')->references('id_hunter')->on('hunter')->onDelete('cascade');